# Running multiple select queries using the same db context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Can you run multiple "select" queries using the same data context? Today at work, I ran into a situation where the query returns inaccurate results when I run multiple "select" queries in the same context using Entity Framework 4. The code is similar to the one below:

```
            using(var dataContext = new VisitorDataContext())
            {
                var v1 = dataContext.Visitor.Where(p => p.VisitorId == 73).FirstOrDefault();

//process v1
                var v2 = dataContext.Visitor.Where(p => p.VisitorId == 98).FirstOrDefault();

//process v2 
                var v3 = dataContext.Visitor.Where(p => p.VisitorId == 100).FirstOrDefault();

//provess v2
            }
```

So what happened to me was that v2 contained previous results from v1. I suspect it's because the context is not disposed until the end of this using block. I'm wondering if in the future, to avoid this error, I should dispose the context after each query.

Answer (score 0):

The DataContext's Change Tracker accumulates all the Entities you fetch over the lifetime of the DataContext.  And the Change Tracker will "fix-up" relationships between Entities fetched in separate queries.  So you might see results from previous queries when examining Navigation Properties.

But that would not affect code like what you posted.  Also you should use EF 6, not EF 4.

Answer (score 0):

The DbContext remembers the items you already fetched. This is needed to be able to change fetched data before you save it.

Example:
Suppose you have a School with many Teachers and many Students; every Teacher has zero or more Students, every Student has zero or more Teachers (many-to-many relation)

Suppose Student [100] is named Theresa, and lives on 'DowningStreet 10, London' She moves. Meanwhile you want to notify all other Students that live nearby about her new Address:

```
var TheresaMay = dbContext.Students.
    .Where(student => student.Id == 100)
    .FirstOrDefault();

// change address of TheresaMay:
theresaMay.Address = "King's College, Oxford",
```

The data is not saved yet, in the database she still Lives in London. If you would use this value, what would you want? The changed value or the database value:

```
var city = theresaMay.City; // London or Oxford?
```

Notify all nearby Students about her new address

```
var nearbyStudents = dbContext.Students
    .Where(student => student.City == theresaMay.City)
    .ToList();
SendMessage(nearbyStudents)
```

Would you want Oxford students to get the notification or would you like London students?

Suppose you want to fetch students grouped by City:

```
var studentsGroupedByCitry = dbContext.Students
    .GroupBy(student => student.City)
    .ToList();
```

Question: Should Theresa be in the group of London students, or in Oxford Students?

The designers of entity framework thought it wise, that once you've fetched TheresaMay and change a property, that for you the value of this property would be the new value, not the value that is still in the database.

Because we don't know whether you succeed to save the changes, others who will fetch TheresaMay still get the database value.

Therfore it is a bit dangerous to keep your context open to query several items, because if someone else changes one of the items you already fetched, you won't see these changes. Hence it is wise only to keep your dbContext for the time you really need. Usually this is about the time your would normally lock the database or the time you would keep a Transaction alive.